# Deploying Roslyn in application targeting .NET Framework 4.6

Tags: c#, roslyn

I maintain an application in which users can influence the application's output by scripting some actions. Those C# source code snippets the user entered are then compiled to an assembly that is referenced and executed at runtime.

For compiling the assembly I am using System.CodeDom.Compiler.CSharpCodeProvider. The application targets the .NET Framework 4.6. **I cannot switch to any other Framework version.**

Now I would like to use Roslyn Compiler APIs to analyze and programatically build the assembly.

I added the NuGet package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp (V 2.7.0) and changed the application's code to make use of Roslyn's Compiler API. My project compiles OK.

But when the application runs and tries to compile the assembly using Roslyn, I get the error that **Microsoft.CSharp.dll** could not be found in then application's BIN directory. So I added the NuGet package for Microsoft.Csharp.

The next error was that **System.Core.dll** could not be found. After also adding this NuGet package it complained about **System.Drawing.dll**.

After adding another 10 packages I could maybe get this to work. But there has got to be another way. Since the application uses System.Drawing itself, I am concerned having unexpected results at runtime.

- Is there a Roslyn version that uses default .NET Framework 4.6 assemblies?
- Is it even possible to deploy the application with a bunch of Roslyn dlls via XCOPY onto the customer's server without installing anything Roslyn related on the target machine?

Comment: CSharpCodeProvider always uses the installed framework version.  So probably 4.7.1 on your machine.  Works well on the user's machine too.  If you target 4.6 for your program then you can be sure that the user's machine has at least 4.6.  It sounds like you are generating code for the wrong platform target, .netcore perhaps.  Actually targeting 4.6 requires the reference assemblies for that version, the kind that you have stored in c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies, but your user won't.  Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: Thank you very much - that was a hint in the right direction! Before compiling the assembly I also add MetadataReferences. The references pointed to the wrong path. Now I am using RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory() to get the directory containing the .NET Framework assemblies.